# Is there any API in SuccessFactors which will give me All Roles and Groups associated with All Users in one go

Tags: java, odata, sap-successfactors

We are trying to fetch Roles and Groups for user in SuccessFactor but if we have 10,000 user then we have hit below API 10000 times which is causing performance issue.

So Is there any API where we get All Roles and Groups for All users in one go

--- Account Aggregation API ---

To List all the groups associate to User:

https://<>/odata/v2/getDynamicGroupsByUser?userId='0909'&groupSubType='permission'&$format=json

List all the roles associate to User:

https://<>/odata/v2/getUserByRBPRole?roleId='0009L'&$format=json

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any API for this...

Comment: https://<>/odata/v2/getUserRolesReport?userIds='rom1,admin'

We have above which will give roles in XML reports for given users, but is it reliable API ?